# Create a single instance of HashMap in Java throughout the session

Tags: java, spring, dictionary, static-methods, static-members

I am working on a project wherein I need to store a set of keys and values throughout the session of the program execution. Meaning when the server is up, I want to have a map which stores data and is same for multiple requests made in that session.

So for creating this map, should I make a **static** Map or create a singleton bean for it and use **autowiring**? Which is better?

I used the static map, but noticed that even after stopping the server and running it again, the map instance was having values from previous session, instead it should have been null in the beginning of the request. The objects were not getting destroyed properly.

Does this behavior is improved if I'll use beans?

Comment: If you really stopped the server, then, static map will not remember the values - it will be empty on start. Not sure why you are seeing values still in there - what kind of server is it?

Comment: Are you talking about HTTP sessions? What do you mean by session? Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to define what is a `Session`.

Usually, in a Web project, a Session is related to an `HTTP Session`. These are managed in Spring by `@Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_SESSION)`. The Bean will have a proxy, managing the instances of your Service automatically.

In this case, you do not want to use a `Static Map`. Indeed, a static object is global to your program, and only one instance will exist at any time, like a `Singleton`.

If you define a Session as the start and end of your server process, then fine.

*So for creating this map, should I make a static Map or create a singleton bean for it and use autowiring?*

This is close to the same thing. The only difference is how it will be instantiated. A static Map will be created by the JVM as soon as your `Class` is loaded. A Singleton Bean will be created by Spring at the first use.

The main advantage of the Bean, in your case, is the `Inversion of Control` for your `Unit Tests`.

*I used the static map, but noticed that even after stopping the server and running it again, the map instance was having values from previous session*

Usually, an object will lose its data when the server is closed, unless your Map has been `Serialized` by the server and stored in a session file on the disk. Maybe you should try to move your static Map to its own Class.

*Does this behavior is improved if I'll use beans?*

No, the behavior will be the same.

Don't forget that, as a singleton, your Map must be synchronized with `Collections.synchronizedMap()`. Otherwise, you will have surprises when using it.